# cmake upgrade on machine with NO root access

Tags: linux, cmake

I need to use the latest CMAKE (actually 3.4.3 or higher, but I want to use 3.7), to configure a package.

On the university machine I am using the CMAKE version is 3.3.2.

I have downloaded the latest tar.gz from cmake website and I tried ./configure but it won't work.

Exporting CMAKE_ROOT path to .bashrc does not work.

How do I use CMAKE 3.7 without having to use root access?

Comment: how exactly `./configure` doesn't work? to build from sources you need to have a working C++ compiler and other prerequisites installed...

Comment: anyway, it wouldn't be "upgrade", but parallel installation of newer `cmake` somewhere at your `$HOME` directory.

Comment: Hi Zaufi, the problem was with Linux_x86-64. I downloaded and configured and installed the default (32 bit) files. It worked. But now I am stuck at make install. trying to solve it by `./configure --prefix=/path/to/install/dir`

Comment: You definitely need to specify some prefix to install, cuz you obviously do not have permissions to install into default one (`/usr/local/`).
I would recommend `./configure --prefix=~/.local` and add `~/.local/bin` to the `PATH` **before** everything else in your `~.bashrc`, so you can use your own `cmake` instead of system-wide, w/o specifying a full path to it.